# Script stops executing once it encounters def line

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, encryption

So, I had 2 scripts, a Vigenere cipher and a Caesar cipher, however, when I decided to merge them into a "mainproject" file by using "import" to import the script after the wanted answer from the user is sent on the Terminal page, when I've done the code and decided to execute the mainproject, I've got the question whether to choose to use Vigenere or Caesar, once I typed caesar (1) it played the first 2-4 lines and stopped the code once I've encountered the "def" line on both of scripts, if thats the problem, I can't use imports with "def", how can I merge them both into one file that asks which script I would like to use?

Caesar:

```py
import time
import sys

print("Welcome to Caesar Cipher")
time.sleep(3)
print("Choose the corresponding number to Encrypt or Decrypt in Caesar Cipher")
def encryption():
    print("Encryption")

    print("You have chose ENCRYPTION")
    msg = input("Enter message: ")
    key = int(input("Enter key(0-25): "))  

    encrypted_text = ""

    for i in range(len(msg)):
        if ord(msg[i]) == 32:  
            encrypted_text += chr(ord(msg[i]))  

        elif ord(msg[i]) + key > 122:

            temp = (ord(msg[i]) + key) - 122   
            encrypted_text += chr(96+temp)

        elif (ord(msg[i]) + key > 90) and (ord(msg[i]) <= 96):

            temp = (ord(msg[i]) + key) - 90
            encrypted_text += chr(64+temp)

        else:

            encrypted_text += chr(ord(msg[i]) + key)

    print("Your Encrypted Message: " + encrypted_text)


def decryption():
    print("Decryption")

    print("You have chose DECRYPTION")
    encrp_msg = input("Enter encrypted Text: ")
    decrp_key = int(input("Enter key(0-25): "))

    decrypted_text = ""

    for i in range(len(encrp_msg)):
        if ord(encrp_msg[i]) == 32:
            decrypted_text += chr(ord(encrp_msg[i]))

        elif ((ord(encrp_msg[i]) - decrp_key) < 97) and ((ord(encrp_msg[i]) - decrp_key) > 90):
            temp = (ord(encrp_msg[i]) - decrp_key) + 26
            decrypted_text += chr(temp)

        elif (ord(encrp_msg[i]) - decrp_key) < 65:
            temp = (ord(encrp_msg[i]) - decrp_key) + 26
            decrypted_text += chr(temp)

        else:
            decrypted_text += chr(ord(encrp_msg[i]) - decrp_key)

    print("Text has been Decrypted: " + decrypted_text)


    choice = int(input("1. Encryption\n2. Decryption\nChoose(1,2): "))
    if choice == 1:
        encryption()
    elif choice == 2:
        decryption()
    else:
        print("Wrong Choice")
```

Vigenere:

```py
import time
print("Welcome to Vigenere Cipher")
time.sleep(2)
print("Choose the corresponding number to Encrypt or Decrypt in Vigenere Cipher")
time.sleep(2.5)
def msg_and_key():
    msg = input("Enter message: ").upper()
    key = input("Enter key: ").upper()

    key_map = ""

    j=0
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        if ord(msg[i]) == 32:
            key_map += " "
        else:
            if j < len(key):
                key_map += key[j]
                j += 1
            else:
                j = 0
                key_map += key[j]
                j += 1

    return msg, key_map


def create_vigenere_table():
    table = []
    for i in range(26):
        table.append([])

    for row in range(26):
        for column in range(26):
            if (row + 65) + column > 90:

                table[row].append(chr((row+65) + column - 26))
            else:
                table[row].append(chr((row+65)+column))


    return table


def cipher_encryption(message, mapped_key):
    table = create_vigenere_table()
    encrypted_text = ""

    for i in range(len(message)):
        if message[i] == chr(32):
            encrypted_text += " "
        else:
            row = ord(message[i])-65
            column = ord(mapped_key[i]) - 65
            encrypted_text += table[row][column]

    print("Encrypted Message: {}".format(encrypted_text))


def itr_count(mapped_key, message):
    counter = 0
    result = ""

    for i in range(26):
        if mapped_key + i > 90:
            result += chr(mapped_key+(i-26))
        else:
            result += chr(mapped_key+i)

    for i in range(len(result)):
        if result[i] == chr(message):
            break
        else:
            counter += 1

    return counter


def cipher_decryption(message, mapped_key):
    table = create_vigenere_table()
    decrypted_text = ""


    for i in range(len(message)):
        if message[i] == chr(32):
            decrypted_text += " "
        else:
            decrypted_text += chr(65 + itr_count(ord(mapped_key[i]), ord(message[i])))

    print("Decrypted Message: {}".format(decrypted_text))


    print("Key and Message can only be alphabetic")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    choice = int(input("1. Encryption\n2. Decryption\nChoose(1,2): "))
    if choice == 1:
        print("You have chose ENCRYPTION")
        message, mapped_key = msg_and_key()
        cipher_encryption(message, mapped_key)

    elif choice == 2:
        print("You have chose DECRYPTION")
        message, mapped_key = msg_and_key()
        cipher_decryption(message, mapped_key)

    else:
        print("Wrong choice")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how/ where do you import? I think you didnt include that part. Also if possible, could you strip the code down to a minimal working example that illustrates the error?

Comment: `def` is only information that you define function. if you use `from module_name import *` then you have to run function `encryption()`, etc. If you use `import module_name` then you have to run `module_name.decryption()`, etc.

Comment: I put the "import" after the line of something like, if the user types "1" then the script would be imported, if the user types 2, the vigenere script would be imported, if anything else it'd print "Wrong choice" etc.

Comment: Add the main script to the question, since that's where you're having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`def` only *defines* a function. To actually execute it you need to call it.

It seems the following part should be outside of `decryption` function body i.e. indented to the left. It:

- call be executed directly on the module level
- can be a separate function e.g. `main` that you can call

As `main`:

```
def main():
    choice = int(input("1. Encryption\n2. Decryption\nChoose(1,2): "))
    if choice == 1:
        encryption()
    elif choice == 2:
        decryption()
    else:
        print("Wrong Choice")
```

And now you can call the `main` function:

```
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. This answer ended up more as general advice than a specific point solution to your problem, but I hope it's helpful.

One obvious remark is that it would be nice not to have to import the code for the cypher you don't intend to use.
Imports are executable statements, so this is quite practical.

Your code is far from optimally organised. Much of the code on the two files is the same or very similar. This is not unusual for new programmers, as it takes a while to learn how to break problems down and extract the common elements. The real problem is that while it defines lots of functions, none of them actually get called (unless there's more code you haven't included).

I would recommend that you modify your code so that there's a top-level program that collects the key and data and performs the required operations, along with your two
encryption/decryption modules. The encryption and decryption routines shouldn't do any input or output at all, just deal with the data.

Let's assume you have a variable `mtype` that holds the type of encryption you want to use. The top-level logic could look something like this:

```
if mtype == "caesar":
    from caesar import encrypt, decrypt
elif mtype == "vigniere":
    from vigniere import encrypt, decrypt
else:
    sys.exit("Unrecognised message type")
```

If this code succeeds you would then have an `encrypt` and a `decrypt` function from the correct module. This means that they have to have the same interface, since your logic must now be written to accommodate either.

The remainder of your logic would look something like this (untested):

```
operation = input("E(ncrypt) or D(ecrypt)? ")
if operation.upper().startswith("E"):
    function = encrypt
elif operation.upper().startswith("D"):
    function = decrypt
else:
    sys.exit("Unknown operation")
message = input(...)
key = input(...)

output = function(message, key)
```

This will hopefully make your code clearer by separating out the I/O responsibility
from the encryption and decryption tasks.